# Magento removed system configuration option still exists, but not in core resource

Tags: magento, configuration, system

Strange issue..
I recently removed some xml options from a system configuration file. But these options still exist when I call Mage::storeConfig() for the relevant paths.

I have:
 - cleared caches (ALL caches...flush, storage, and all checkboxes flush)
 - checked the core config data table for the entry
 - reindexed data
 - manually cleared /var folders
 - Exported the DB, and performed a text search for the entry

Where could it possibly be getting these values still?

thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

Let's say you have:

```
<default>
    <design>
        <head translate="default_description" module="page">
            <default_title>Magento Commerce</default_title>
        </head>
    </design>
</default>
```

Inside

> app\code\core\Mage\Page\etc\config.xml

If you call...

```
Mage::getStoreConfig( 'design/head/default_title' );
```

Output is

> Magento Commerce

Now if you go to the admin panel or

```
core_config_data
```

> Path: design/head/default_title

And customize this value to be My Test

Calling...
    Mage::getStoreConfig( 'design/head/default_title' );

Will net you 'My Test'

Essentially these are layout.xml default fallbacks for core_config_data table values that have not yet been entered/customized.

To clear the value in your initial question.

Go to your database:

```
SELECT *
FROM
core_config_data
WHERE
path
LIKE '%your/config/path/you're/trying/to/delete%'
```

Comment: I misread your answer at first. I have checked my core_config table

But I do still have an entry in my modules config.xml file...in the <default> node, for the old system config value.
 Guess its retrieving from that location. Not what I would expect though....learn something new everyday! Thanks  :)